# Disable href function is not working with onmouseup event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to disabled the hyperlink after it was opened in new tab using one right click, so that I call the `onmouseup` event and checked for right click and call disable function. But the disable functionality not work here. I don't want to hide the link, I just want to disable the link.

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<a id="1" href="link1.html" onmouseup="if(event.button==2){disable(this.id)}">link_1</a>
<a id="2" href="link2.html" onmouseup="if(event.button==2){disable(this.id)}">link_2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and JavaScript,

```
<script>
function disable(get)
{
 document.get.style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Can any one have idea on this?

Comment: In case you were not aware, it is invalid to have an element id starting with a number in HTML4.01. This is not the case for HTML5 compatible documents. Please see [here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) for a longer explaination.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to accomplish by setting `display:block` on the `<a>` but the error you should be seeing in the browser is a JavaScript one because you `document.get` is incorrect.

Since you are passing the element id to the `disable()` function you could use

```
document.getElementById(get).style.display = 'block';
```

to set the display property.

Or just pass `this` instead like so:

#### HTML

```
<a id="1" href="link1.html" onmouseup="if(event.button==2){disable(this)}">link_1</a>
<a id="2" href="link2.html" onmouseup="if(event.button==2){disable(this)}">link_2</a>
```

​

#### JavaScript

```
function disable(theLink) {
    theLink.style.display="block";
}​
```

To address the *disable* problem, setting `display:block` will not disable the link. You might want to look at adding an `onclick` function to consume the click event as demonstrated at [Disable link using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929598/disable-link-using-javascript) and/or modifying the `<a>` style to indicate that it is disabled, for example setting the color to grey.